# Why two IA creates problems?

Tags: alphametic

IA creates lots of debates about potential problems such as overtaking humans or destroying jobs. I'm not sure about AI but since 1985 Terminator, I know that two IA ("*Intelligence Artificielle*) surely creates a problem :

```
  I A
+ I A
-----
  P B
```

But can someone explain why ^^ ?

## My attempt

### Domains

- $D(A) = D(I) = \{1,..., 9\}$
- $D(P) = D(B) = \{0,..., 9\}$

### Constraints

- $10(I + I) + (A + A) = 10P + B$

I tried to use what I believe to be backtrack research.

1. $A= \{I = 1\} \rightarrow$ consistant
2. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0\} \rightarrow$ consistant
3. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 0\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant
4. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 1\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant
5. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 2\} \rightarrow$ consistant
6. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 2, B = 0\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant
7. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 2, B = 1\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant
8. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 2, B = 2\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant
9. $A = \{I = 1, A = 0, P = 2, B = 3\} \rightarrow$ inconsistant car $A+A = 0 \neq 3$

   ... until we change the value from A to 2 (because I already equal to 1) so far I don't know the answer.

Comment: are you expecting a unique solution? Seems like there are many possibilities...

Comment: @KateGregory Ideally but it's not a constraint

Comment: Even with the new constraints, I found 5 answers in no time.

Comment: @Duck, the constraints is logically deduced from the equation

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all sure what the question is. Here's some info based on what I think is the question

> There are 27 solutions. Among these,
>  $a,p\in\{1,...,9\},\ b\in\{0,2,4,6,8\},\ i\in\{0,...,4\}$.
>  [Here's some code that generates the possible solutions](https://repl.it/@rshields/FixedSecondaryComputation)

Comment: A good puzzle is, "Alice gives Bob [this equation]. Bob does not know the answer. Alice tells Bob what A is. Bob now knows the answer."